# JSON Data Collect using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is the JSON data

```
{"code":1,"msg":"Successful","details":{"merchant_id":"7","restaurant_name":"BTEST","country":"India","address":"XXXX","service":"2","contact_phone":"+91111111111","open":false,"merchant_close_store":false,"minimum_order":"","minimum_order_raw":"","logo":"https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/TEST.png","delivery_fee":"Rs. 20.00","delivery_fee_raw":"20","ratings":{"ratings":"4.5","votes":"2"},"offers_found":1,"free_delivery":1,"cuisine":"Restaurant","can_checkout":{"code":2,"msg":"Sorry merchant is closed.","button":"","holiday":2,"is_pre_order":2},"enabled_table_booking":1,"coordinates":{"latitude":"null","longtitude":"null"}},"request":"{\"item_id\":\"2632\",\"merchant_id\":\"7\",\"cat_id\":\"9\",\"lang_id\":\"null\",\"lang\":\"null\",\"api_key\":\"null\",\"app_version\":\"null\"}"}
```

I Want to Collect the "request" under the "item_id" using javascript

Comment: `JSON.parse(myObject.request).item_id` (`myObject` represent your JSON object)

Comment: Sir i am collect "details" under "merchant_id"  use of

Comment: var merchant_id =data.details.merchant_id

Comment: Good that should work, what is your question then ?

Comment: when i collect data from "request" under item_id

Comment: Have you used `var item_id = JSON.parse(data.request).item_id` ??

Comment: var item_id =data.request.item_id but the problem was under the "request" a another json how should i collect the data

Comment: I have already posted the solution two times (you should parse the `request` too as a json), have you tried it?

Comment: Gald I could help, happy coding.

Comment: hello, can you help me again?

Comment: Yes sure, how can I do ?

Comment: {"code":1,"msg":"OK","details":{"gallery_photo":["https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg","https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg","https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg"]}}

Comment: how can i create a slider ?

Comment: function displayItemGall(data)
{       

  var gallery = JSON.parse(data).gallery_photo;
  var html_gallery='';
    
    
    
       $.each(gallery, function( key, val ) {
                 
           
      html_gallery+='<a>';
            html_gallery+='<img src="'+val+'" data-src="'+val+'" class="preload-image responsive-image" alt="img">';
      html_gallery+='</a>';
            
            
       });
       
       
       
    
              
       createElement("item-info2",html_gallery);
}

Comment: store the datacase "getItemDetails":
     
     displayItemGall(data.details);
     
    break;